# QBO3 Unable to cache error

Tags: javascript, caching

I noticed these warnings yesterday when I try to refresh certain pages in a QBO3 system:

[image]

What is the root cause, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This error will occur if your browser's `sessionStorage` is full. You can resolve the error by shutting down and restarting your browser (entirely), or issuing this javascript command:

```
sessionStorage.clear();
```

---

Session storage enables using javascript to explicitly store data on a user's hard drive. User may limit the amount of storage, and can turn session storage off. If left on, properly used session storage can greatly enhance the user's experience.

Session storage is built into the `qbo3.AbstractObject` javascript class. Every time `invokeHtml` is called, the results are saved in a cache. When a panel is rendered, the `qbo3.ObjectBind` behavior will attempt to read the panel results from session storage, and will display the results if available.

#### Dashboard Example

The Valuation dashboard user experience is:

- Navigate to the Valuation dashboard (`Valuation.ashx/Home`)

  - There are two panels: a dashboard panel and a search panel
  - On the first visit, neither panel is in session storage
  - The dashboard panel will render the default dashboard by requesting data from the server, and the dashboard results will be saved to session storage
  - The search panel will not be rendered, since no search requests have been issued
  - Click on a link inside the dashboard, rendering the corresponding results
    in the search panel
  - The search panel will request data from the server, and the search results will be saved to session storage
  - Click on a Valuation hyperlink, navigating away from the Valuation Dashboard
  - Click on a link to revisit the Valuation Dashboard (or just
    click back)
  - The dashboard panel will render from session storage
  - The search panel will render from session storage, showing the user their
    last search results

#### Summary Example

In the `Summary`, we have to be a bit more careful about our cache. If we are caching, say, an Attachment panel, we must ensure we don't mix the Attachment for Valuation 12345 with those from Valuation 23456. This can be done by specifying a cache key:

```
<div id="attachmentList" class="span12" data-behavior="ObjectBind" data-objectbind-options="{{ 
  'class': 'qbo3.AttachmentObject', 
  'cacheKey': 'AttachmentList-Valuation-{//ValuationID[1]}', 
  'method': 'Search', 
  'data': {{ 'Object': 'Valuation', 'ObjectID' : '{//ValuationID[1]}' }} 
}}">.</div>
```

This ensures that javascript does not mix the cache results for Valuation 12345 with those form Valuation 23456 (or any other Valuation).

In some cases, it is desirable to cache the panel content for a limited duration. For Summary page panels, it is often reasonable to cache content for 10 minutes, but not all day. The `ObjectBind` behavior enables a `maxCacheDuration` setting (measured in minutes) as follows:

```
<div id="attachmentList" class="span12" data-behavior="ObjectBind" data-objectbind-options="{{ 
  'class': 'qbo3.AttachmentObject', 
  'cacheKey': 'AttachmentList-Valuation-{//ValuationID[1]}', 
  'maxCacheDuration': 10,
  'method': 'Search', 
  'data': {{ 'Object': 'Valuation', 'ObjectID' : '{//ValuationID[1]}' }} 
}}">.</div>
```